# Parse multiple RSS feeds with PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss

Hey so im building a hobby rss reader in php.
Im retrieving the data just fine, but I failed attempting to get multiple feeds into a one big array.

I have a `core/sources` file with URLs on each line. For example:

```
https://www.adamov.cz/media/rss.php
https://ct24.ceskatelevize.cz/rss/hlavni-zpravy
```

Both examples are valid RSS. But if i loop through this file, adding it to an array and forlooping it, i always get the data just from the last one in that file:

```
        if (file_exists("core/sources")) {


        $URLItems = array_filter(explode("\n", file_get_contents('core/sources')));
        $totalPosts = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i<count($URLItems); $i++) {
            $feeds = simplexml_load_file($URLItems[$i]);
            $sourceName = $feeds->channel->title;
            array_push($totalPosts, (string) $sourceName);
        }
```

This will just print " Array ( [0] => [1] => ČT 24 - Hlavní zprávy ) ", if i swap the order, it would print the other URLs title.

```
        print_r($totalPosts);
```

How is that? Do i need to exit the simplexml file read or something? Cannot figure this out.

Comment: It will print two titles, based on the code given:
`array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(31) "Město Adamov - Hlavní zprávy"
  [1]=>
  string(28) "

ČT 24 - Hlavní zprávy

"
}`

Comment: would it? then it might just be a problem with my php then

Comment: i will test it on my work pc again and will close the question if so. thank you

Comment: http://codepad.org/2Lgtze71  Although the simple xml function is disabled on this server here you see two items in the output array.